# jQuery code order with $.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I dont even know how to exactly explain my problem. So I have tried different methods for object variable been sent from server to client side, with $.post().
I had $.post() method inside the loop and it fills array with objects.

From my code:

```
var array = new Array;
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    $.post("path",{ id: i })
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            array.push(data);
    },"json");
}
console.log(array);
```

So in console first that outputs is `console.log(array);` and ofcourse its empty, and later when I want to use the array that code too executes faster that first loop.

Later I decited to do what I want with these objects in `.done` function.

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    $.post("path",{ id: i })
         .done(function(data){
              alert(data.id);
              //do stuff with data object
         },"json");
}
console.log(array);
```

But in alert it shows what id's he loads, and they are not in the order from 0 - 9, but in this case order is important for me. Last time load order: 0 7 4 9 1 3 4 2 5 6 8. In server side everything is ok, I use `json_encode($obj)` to transfer object.

Can someone please explain why my order are wrong? I tried to load 3 elements but still 80% of tries the order are wrong. I could try to pass whole array of objects, but vant do that with `json_encode`

Sorry if there is some mistake in code but I didnt copy it from file, with syntax all is ok, but how to manage the order??

Comment: Why don't you just use one and only one request sending all relevant data to server?

Comment: The requests come back in a different order because they are asynchronous and the order that the server processes them (and the speed in which the response is generated) in is not guaranteed. You should change the logic to send all data in one request. This will be faster and save server load.

Comment: both rory and david comments right to me

Comment: I tried to pass variables `from: 0, to: 10` then pass array of objects to client side, but it returnet me empty array. I read about `__sleep()` function in object class, but didnt understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve your goal is to wait for completion of each of your asynchronous calls.

```js
var array = [];

function doAsyncCall(id) {
    if (id < 10) {
        $.post('path', { 'id': id }, function (data) {
            array.push(data.id);
            doAsyncCall(id + 1);
        });
    }
}

doAsyncCall(0);
console.log(array); -> should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but in console I get warnimg about similar HTML requests each time I run the call. But I think thats something in my syntax. Tomorow will give a try for all other suggestions.

Comment: Nice this is teh answer. Thanks man. I tried to do async too, but it blockts all browser and animations so not for me, but this is good.

Answer (score 0):

The requests you make are async, and the response time will vary. What happens is that the `done` handler will be executed **when** in a random order and at that time is not possible to put the responses in the order you are looking for.

For this I see 2 possible solutions:

- reorder the array after you get all responses
- make a queue of sync requests, one request after the other

Comment: How can I make this queue of requests?

Comment: See my answer for concrete example.

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest that you use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.post()` as it's much more customizable.

```
var array = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: path,
    data: { id: i },
    async:false,   //here you can set synchronous behaviour 
    dataType :  "json"
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        array.push(data);
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[jQuery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**</kbd>

Comment: why does this get -1? Could the down-voter add a comment explaining the reasons?

Comment: This seems good, but I think there is a reson why someone put you -1, but I will give a try

Comment: Your solution blocks the entire web application. I don't think it's the best way.

Comment: How blocks the entire web application?

Comment: But for example if I send only 3 requests per some time does the effect on web page is big??

Comment: Did you read the documentation you linked to @Sadikhasan? -> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.
And @veiss, the answer to your question is in my post...

Comment: I guess that this is downvoted because its advcating the use of synchronous requests (which are very bad practice and will block the UI) and using this over `$.post` offers absolutely no benefit to the OP.